# Prepend a 9 or append a 0?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Given a positive integer $x$, will $x$ always be larger if one prepends a 9 in comparison to appending a 0?

For x = 1, prepending is largest because $91 > 10$

For x = 9, prepending is largest because $99 > 90$

Comment: By playing a bit with your example, you will see that prepending is always better unless $x$ is made only of $9$ digits (that is, $x=10^n-1$). For example, if $x$ does not start with a $9$ (on the left), then prepending is obviously better, now continue with 2dn digit, etc. And when $x=10^n-1$, prepending is also obviously better. Hence for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is an $n$-digit number, then $10^n>a$.

Then $9\cdot 10^n>9a$.

Then $9\cdot 10^n+a>10a$.

The left side of the last inequality represents prepending a $9$.  The right side represents appending a $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Prepending a $9$ is equivalent to changing the original number $x$ to $9*10^{\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor+1}+x$. Appending a $0$ is equivalent to $10x$. We then have $9*10^{\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor+1}+x>10x$, which simplifies to $10^{\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor+1}>x$, the left-hand side of which is the first power of $10$ greater than $x$, and thus greater than $x$.

Comment: A good strategy in writing mathematics is that if you find yourself repeatedly writing some expression like $\lfloor \log_{10}\rfloor + 1$ as a part of a larger expression, let that suggest that the quantity $\lfloor \log_{10}\rfloor + 1$ is important and deserves to have a name.  In this case you might say "Let $n$ be the number of digits in the original number $x$; then $n = \lfloor \log_{10} x\rfloor + 1$. ..."  Then all the expressions get simpler and the whole thing is easier to understand.